# Why does my state not get set after page reload React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, asynchronous, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('jwt')
    if(token && !user.name) {
        fetch('http://10.129.2.23:8080/me', {
            headers: {
                token: token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
           console.log(data)
            setUser({
                ...user,
                id: data.id,
                name: data.name,
                bio: data.bio,
                posts: data.posts,
                profile_image: data.posts
            })
        })
    }
},[])
```

I am trying to set my user but only the user name stays in the usestate after the useeffect. I dont understand why the bio profile image dont stay after im setting the state. It works in the beginning but when i refresh i lose the information

```
let initialSignup = {name: '', password: ''}
const [signUp, setSignUp] = useState(initialSignup)
const [logIn, setLogIn] = useState(initialSignup)
const [user, setUser] = useState({name: ""})


function handleSignUpChange(e) {
    setSignUp({
        ...signUp,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}

function handleSignUpSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(signUp)
    fetch('http://10.129.2.23:8080/newuser', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(signUp)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        setSignUp(initialSignup)
        sessionStorage.setItem("jwt", data.token)
        setUser({
            ...user,
            id: data.user.id,
            name: data.user.name,
            bio: data.user.bio,
            profile_image: data.user.profile_image
        })
    })
}

function handleLogInChange(e){
    setLogIn({
        ...logIn,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}


// LOG IN
function handleLogInSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('http://10.129.2.23:8080/login',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(logIn)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
        sessionStorage.setItem("jwt", data.token)
        setUser({
            ...user,
            id: data.user.id,
            name: data.user.name,
            bio: data.user.bio,
            profile_image: data.user.profile_image
        })
    })
}
```

This is where i initially set the user in a different component i pass down the prop and the set state

Comment: Could you include the additional code that utilizes the userState hook?

Comment: yes i just edited it where i set the state also

Comment: You need to persist state using ```asyncStorage```

Comment: I mean ```localStorage```, you could also maybe use ```sessionStorage``` to save the user like you did with ```data.token```

Comment: I also noticed that in your handleLogInSubmit(e) method you're passing data.user.<field> items to the setUser() method. But in the useEffect() method, you're passing just data.<field> items to setUser() instead. Could this be a possible reason for the unexpected behavior upon reload?